# Symfony2 can't find ruby.xml in assetic filters

Tags: ruby, symfony, symfony-2.3, assetic

need your help.

Just installed compass and sass, and after reloading page, I've got this error:

> InvalidArgumentException: The file "filters/ruby.xml" does not exist (in: /var/www/ProjectName/Symfony/vendor/symfony/assetic-bundle/Symfony/Bundle/AsseticBundle/DependencyInjection/../Resources/config).

How can I reinstall or create the file.?

Comment: Which version of assetic?

Comment: Have you do `php app/consolle assets:install`?

Comment: DonCallisto Yeah I've done php app/console assets:install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your Assetic config is incorrect, and it tries to load configuration for a non-existent `ruby` filter. I assume that `assetic.filters` section of your configuration looks like this:

```
assetic:
    # ...
    filters:
        ruby:
            apply_to: "\.sass$"
```

Assetic looks up a filter configuration that matches the `filters` array keys, and it sure cannot find a `ruby` filter. You should use `sass` filter instead:

```
assetic:
    # ...
    filters:
        sass:
            apply_to: "\.scss$"
```

Comment: @kaizer, na zdorovie! :)